# Automated Certificate Management enabled on Heroku but still no https and errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I've upgraded to Hobby Heroku plan to get automated `SSL`.

I have a rails app and I have enabled `"config.force_ssl = true"` on `config/environments/production.rb` file. So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong to get https instead of http.

`"SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN"` this is what I get when I visit my site on every browser.

```
heroku certs:auto
=== Automatic Certificate Management is enabled on xxxx.com

Certificate details:
Common Name(s): www.xxxxxxxx.com
Expires At:     2020-10-28 09:19 UTC
Issuer:         /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Starts At:      2020-07-30 09:19 UTC
Subject:        /CN=www.xxxxxxxxx.com
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.

Domain            Status       Last Updated
────────────────  ───────────  ────────────
www.xxxxxxxxx.com  Cert issued  13 minutes
```

I have a `GoDaddy` domain name and is it possible that I've made a mistake over there to cause this ? Domain is working just fine but no https.

Comment: Can you share the domain?

Comment: Did you verify that your app is serving the certificate you just setup? Run:  $ openssl s_client -connect <dns target>:443 -servername <your domain>      The docs are found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl    Also, run $ curl -vI https://www.your_site.com  and paste the output.

Comment: Domain provider was the GoDaddy and apparently all I had to do was to wait a little bit more heroku to apply changes. All sorted. Sorry for the drama. Thanks Uwe Allner to fix my beginner mistakes with the highlighting.